# Repeater signal drops at regular interval

Tags: repeater, ht

Relatively inexperienced ham, starting to call into local nets. With two of the local repeaters the signal drops at regular intervals, approx every 15 seconds. I’ll have a strong signal and then nothing for a fraction of a second.

I’m on a HT with a rubber duck antenna. Moving to another location, or outside doesn’t resolve the problem.

Signal is strong and clear, except for the consistent signal drop.

This doesn’t happen on every repeater that I’ve called into, so far I’ve only noticed it on 2 repeaters.

Haven’t been able to find anything googling about, and I haven’t been able to catch anyone locally that has an idea on what I can try to troubleshoot.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update with model with what specific model HT you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds somewhat like priority scanning.  In this case the radio jumps to the priority channel every few seconds to sample it for activity.  How this is done and how it is programmed depends on your specific radio.  See if your user manual says anything about priority scanning.  Also, Google "priority scan".

Comment: Thanks. It turns out it was the Weather Alert feature on the radio. It was dropping out to check the weather, and then hoping back over.